# Both Windows and Ubuntu on my PC but no dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

My PC used to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I somehow managed to trash both Ubuntu and my UEFI BIOS tool, so was in a bit of a pickle. I have use the Flashback USB system to resolve the UEFI BIOS issue, and have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to replace to former installation. I was not offered a dual boot option during installation, and there is no GRUB menu during booting. I can force either Windows or Ubuntu to boot by going through the BIOS override, but this seems a bit clunky.

I'm not very familiar with GRUB. Is there a way to add a menu for these choices now? There remains a partition on the machine called "ubuntu" which, when booted, leaves me at the GRUB prompt. I assume this is a remnant of the former installation or something. Am I supposed to create a script in this and make it the default boot partition? Kind out of my depth.

Thanks.

Comment: Grub adds what it sees to its menu, but if it can't see Windows (hibernated, disk problems, etc.) and it only sees the one Ubuntu install, by default, it will not even display a menu (force it by holding down a key).  Check your Windows fast boot off, disk OK.